# AsyncAPI apicurio data model additionaProperties:true

Tags: java, model, redhat, asyncapi

In apicurio data model additionalProperties variable is using AsyncApiSchema type, it cannot give the value as true when it comes to create schema for

`map<map<json>>  offset`

Here json will be dynamic. Isn't it good to have it as the type of Object in java.. Or is there any way to set this please point out to me . Thank you

[image: Apicurio data model asyncapi schema]

I was trying to change the type of variable additionalProperties in to java Object , but like in methods , variables cannot be override in java, therefore I got no solution.. but I have used it like this

```
offset:
 type: object
   additionalProperties:
       type: object
         additionalProperties: {}
```

I want to know this is right or not

Answer (score 1):

I think only #asyncapi tag is not enough, cause you are enfaced with the issue in external implementation, provided by Red Hat. They are working with AsyncAPI, OpenAPI in their own way, so this is why I can't provide you with any helpful answer.

I merged fix to jasyncapi and in 1.0.0-eap-2 you can use `additionalProperties` to store boolean or Schema value

fix: https://github.com/asyncapi/jasyncapi/pull/131

Comment: Yeah I will add more hashtags. thank you